# Create Entity every month with suffix automatically in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create an application, where we need to create table every month.
For example : demo_October_2020, demo_November_2020.

I have created Naming strategy by extending SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy that create tables with name_month_year.

When I start my server it creates entity as required.
My problem is, **Entity Should be automatically created every month without restarting the server.**

Is there any way we can **automatically create Entity every month**?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but you are doing it wrong. I'm not sure what the exact reasons for this are but I'm almost 100% sure this is not a good approach. You might look into partitioned tables or if your database doesn't support those into views over a set of tables, or just renaming tables. Also if you create a question with the original problem that made you come up with this approach probably someone can provide a better one.

Comment: I have ERP system, which inserts lots of data every minute so need to create separate table for every month of data.

Comment: That is exactly the use case for partitioned tables.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to do it with spring boot + JPA + Hibernate ?
As I am creating the Models(I have 4 tables with foreign key mapping ) and using spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update 
to create/update table in database

Comment: It is completely independent of Spring, Hibernate and JPA. It's a database feature, so you have to consult your database documentation. See for example https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/partitioned-tables-and-indexes

Comment: i do not think spring can be of any use here i guess, you need to create a database trigger and call a stored procedure which create a new table